# How I can alter this form using another module?

Tags: forms

```
function client_form($form, &$form_submit) {
  $form['Client_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Client Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#value'=> nameget(),
    //'#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['Address'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Address'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['City'] = array(
    '#title' => t('City'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options'=> getcitylist(),
    //'#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['Cityadd'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Enter a new city'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    //'#required' => TRUE,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: use hook_form_alter in your custom module. Find more at http://befused.com/drupal/form-alter

Comment: Just showing code doesn't mean asking a question. The question in title alone doesn't count as _question_. You need to describe also what you exactly don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$form['form_id']['#value']` is set using dpm(). or simply by visiting form display and using element inspection in browser. Most of the time it is like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form">
```

If yes, then you can implement in two ways:

- [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7): If you have less forms to alter. This is specific avoiding checking form_ids and long switch statements to alter multiple forms as in hook_form_alter().
- [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7): If you have many form that needs alter. This runs for all forms. This is global.

Else set it up on form.

Answer (score 0):

By using hook_form_alter you can alter a form.

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   //Check with your form_id 
   if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
        //Alter fields here
   }
}
```

Comment: Sir,Is there requirement to return this form like return $form